# How to change the track color of a SwitchCompat

Tags: android, colors, switchcompat

I've tried using the following link to change the color of a SwitchCompat:

[How to change the color of a SwitchCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714864/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-switchcompat)

Notice the low constrast in my switch:

[image: The SwitchCompat]

But after changing all relevant color values the track (the brighter grey) of the SwitchCompat remains the same. I don't want to change the appearance except the color. The thumb is in pink, and I want the track to have some contrast. Did I miss to define a value in my styles.xml?

I tried these values (random non-white colors):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/first</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/second</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/third</item>
   ...
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/first</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/first</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/second</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/second</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/second</item>
...>
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

I had same probrem and solved it.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   ...
   <!-- Active thumb color & Active track color(30% transparency) -->
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/theme</item>
   <!-- Inactive thumb color -->
   <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/grey300</item>
   <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
   <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/grey600</item>
   ...
</style>
```

I read app compat code, and understand it.

`android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.java`

```
private ColorStateList getSwitchTrackColorStateList() {
    if (mSwitchTrackStateList == null) {
        final int[][] states = new int[3][];
        final int[] colors = new int[3];
        int i = 0;

        // Disabled state
        states[i] = new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_enabled };
        colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(android.R.attr.colorForeground, 0.1f);
        i++;

        states[i] = new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked };
        colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(R.attr.colorControlActivated, 0.3f);
        i++;

        // Default enabled state
        states[i] = new int[0];
        colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(android.R.attr.colorForeground, 0.3f);
        i++;

        mSwitchTrackStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    }
    return mSwitchTrackStateList;
}
```

Comment: any way to set different Active thumb color & Active track color ? instead of the 30% transparency difference in same color.

Comment: @ir2pid : You can specify a drawable.

Comment: I have multiple switches in the same activity, how do i set different colors for each of them???

Comment: Mind my asking how you read the source code?
I downloaded the source code but found nothing about this class.
Do you read it by this link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1949ae9aeaadf52ad7bd7bb74ca5419c67ea7f65/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager.java
Could you also share some experience or method to read the source code?

Comment: what about androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat I cannot hange the style at all?

Comment: this also set the color of text to same color as button so it's not shown well

Answer (score 15):

Below is the **AppCompat** way of changing both the track and thumb color **programmatically**, for a specific **SwitchCompat**. For this example, I have hardcoded the `thumbColor` to red. Ideally, you would set the color through a second method parameter.

Please note that when the switch is checked, a ripple is displayed. The ripple color will not be changed by the code below.

```
public static void setSwitchColor(SwitchCompat v) {
    // thumb color of your choice
    int thumbColor = Color.RED;

    // trackColor is the thumbColor with 30% transparency (77)
    int trackColor = Color.argb(77, Color.red(thumbColor), Color.green(thumbColor), Color.blue(thumbColor));

    // setting the thumb color
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(v.getThumbDrawable(), new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{
                    thumbColor,
                    Color.WHITE
            }));

    // setting the track color
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(v.getTrackDrawable(), new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{
                    trackColor,
                    Color.parseColor("#4D000000") // full black with 30% transparency (4D)
            }));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

if you want to costumize the color of track.you can use this solution.

> track selector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/checked_color" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/checked_color" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/unchecked_color" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/unchecked_color" android:state_selected="false" />
```

**where checked_color and unchecked_color are color of your choices.**

> styles.xml

```
<style name="mySwitchStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
       <!-- do here for additional costumization on thumb, track background,text appearance -->


    </style>


<style name="mySwitchTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="switchStyle">@style/mySwitchStyle</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="trackTint">@color/track_selector</item>
    </style>
```

> layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:theme="@style/mySwitchTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Comment: helpful solution

Answer (score 6):

With the **`MaterialSwitch`** provided by the Material Components Library.

- Use the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute to override the app color for the Switch.

```
  <style name="CustomWidget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/CustomCompoundButton_Switch</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CustomCompoundButton_Switch" >
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
  </style>
```

And in the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch"
    ../>
```

[image][image]

- Use the `style` attribute:

```
  <style name="CustomStyleWidget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch"
         parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="useMaterialThemeColors">false</item>
    <item name="trackTint">@color/track_selector</item>
    <item name="thumbTint">@color/thumb_selector</item>
  </style>
```

with thumb_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/switchTrackDisable"/>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/switchThumbActive" />
  <item android:color="@color/switchThumbkNormal" />
</selector>
```

and track_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/switchTrackDisable"/>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/switchTrackActive" />
  <item android:color="@color/switchTrackNormal" />
</selector>
```

And in the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
    style="@style/CustomStyleWidget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch"
    ../>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a more switches in multiple colors in one Activity, you can use this solution (based on theme by @Konifar):

```
<style name="CustomSwitchTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <!-- Active thumb color & Active track color(30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/custom</item>
    <!-- Inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#E0E0E0</item>
    <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#757575</item>
</style>
```

where `@color/custom` is color of thumb when switch is activated.

Then apply this theme to your SwitchCompat this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitchTheme" />
```

Comment: androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat - it cannot be changed when migrating to androidX

Answer (score 4):

```
 Here is Switch Layout
 -Adding theme to your switch to change the color of track.Check the style given below:-.

**Switch Compact**
  <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/goOnlineBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/Switch_style/>


**Switch_style**
   <style name="Switch_style" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="trackTint">@color/white</item>
   </style>
```

Where trackTint will change your track color

Answer (score 2):

Here is how a developer can change the track drawable of a SwitchCompat:
First, in the root layout, write `xmlns:SwitchCompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
Then:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/your_switch_thumb"
        SwitchCompat:track="@drawable/your_switch_track_selector" 
        />
```

where your_switch_track_selector can be:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_ios_track_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_ios_track_off" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>

1.switch_ios_track_on:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <solid android:color="#4EDA62" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>

2.switch_ios_track_off:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <solid android:color="#E3E3E3" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Simple and easy..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Finally solved it programatically with this Kotlin code

```
fun tintSwitchButton(sw: SwitchCompat, resolvedColor: Int) {
    val states = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_pressed),
            intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed)
    )

    DrawableCompat.setTintList(sw?.trackDrawable, ColorStateList(
            states,
            intArrayOf(resolvedColor, resolvedColor)
    ))

    DrawableCompat.setTintList(sw?.thumbDrawable, ColorStateList(
            states,
            intArrayOf(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE)
    ))
}
```

And the function call is

```
tintSwitchButton(switchCompat, Color.rgb(214, 0, 0))
```

You can also create an extension function:

```
fun SwitchCompat.tint(resolvedColor: Int) {
    val states = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_pressed),
        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed)
    )

    DrawableCompat.setTintList(trackDrawable, ColorStateList(
        states,
        intArrayOf(resolvedColor, resolvedColor)
    ))

    DrawableCompat.setTintList(thumbDrawable, ColorStateList(
        states,
        intArrayOf(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE)
    ))
}
```

So the call would be easier

```
switchCompat.tint(Color.rgb(214,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

just use colorControlActivated to set the color of SwitchCompat's track and thumb.

If not set, the default colorControlActivated color will use colorAccent.
(from the experience, still not find where in the source code).

The source code changed and does not still like @Ovidiu said.
But still thanks him for let me know to find the answer from the source code.

```
mThumbDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SwitchCompat_android_thumb);
```

will eventually call the following method.

/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager.java

```
private ColorStateList createSwitchTrackColorStateList(Context context) {
    final int[][] states = new int[3][];
    final int[] colors = new int[3];
    int i = 0;

    // Disabled state
    states[i] = ThemeUtils.DISABLED_STATE_SET;
    colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(context, android.R.attr.colorForeground, 0.1f);
    i++;

    states[i] = ThemeUtils.CHECKED_STATE_SET;
    colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(context, R.attr.colorControlActivated, 0.3f);
    i++;

    // Default enabled state
    states[i] = ThemeUtils.EMPTY_STATE_SET;
    colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(context, android.R.attr.colorForeground, 0.3f);
    i++;

    return new ColorStateList(states, colors);
}

private ColorStateList createSwitchThumbColorStateList(Context context) {
    final int[][] states = new int[3][];
    final int[] colors = new int[3];
    int i = 0;

    final ColorStateList thumbColor = getThemeAttrColorStateList(context,
            R.attr.colorSwitchThumbNormal);

    if (thumbColor != null && thumbColor.isStateful()) {
        // If colorSwitchThumbNormal is a valid ColorStateList, extract the default and
        // disabled colors from it

        // Disabled state
        states[i] = ThemeUtils.DISABLED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = thumbColor.getColorForState(states[i], 0);
        i++;

        states[i] = ThemeUtils.CHECKED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(context, R.attr.colorControlActivated);
        i++;

        // Default enabled state
        states[i] = ThemeUtils.EMPTY_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = thumbColor.getDefaultColor();
        i++;
    } else {
        // Else we'll use an approximation using the default disabled alpha

        // Disabled state
        states[i] = ThemeUtils.DISABLED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = getDisabledThemeAttrColor(context, R.attr.colorSwitchThumbNormal);
        i++;

        states[i] = ThemeUtils.CHECKED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(context, R.attr.colorControlActivated);
        i++;

        // Default enabled state
        states[i] = ThemeUtils.EMPTY_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = getThemeAttrColor(context, R.attr.colorSwitchThumbNormal);
        i++;
    }

    return new ColorStateList(states, colors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SwitchCompat is a Material Design widget. 
when my activity extends **AppCompatActivity** and android:theme="@style/mySwitch" is worked.