# SwitchPreference default color

Tags: java, android, xml

the application I am working on I have set the primary/dark/accent colors to the colors I desire and they appear in the correct locations (as expected). I have a preference activity that I am using though, and I was hoping that the color of the `preferenceswitch`'s that I am using would render in the accent color. Instead they are rendering in the material teal color. I was wondering is this default behavior with Lollipop, like in Kitkat it was the blue? I don't even reference the color which is `#009688` anywhere in my code or my `colors.xml` / `styles.xml`.

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#00BCD4</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#0097A7</color>
    <color name="accent">#FFD740</color>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Any Ideas? I'll provide any more info. I saw some stuff on here about creating custom stuff, but is that really necessary?

**preferenceActivity.java**

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PrefFrag prefFragment = new PrefFrag();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, prefFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using `Theme.AppCompat` with `android:colorPrimary` - generally you'd use the non-prefixed colors if you are using `AppCompat`. How is your `PreferenceActivity` set up?

Comment: Sorry, I'm away from the computer now. But do you mean in styles.xml I'd generally say `@color/primary` etc. I've never done much with lollipop development so sorry if obvious

Comment: AppCompat uses `<item name="colorPrimary">` not `<item name="android:colorPrimary">` - just wondering how you were combining AppCompat and a PreferenceActivity together.

Comment: Updated OP w/ `preferenceActivity`

Comment: Hey wow. That worked. If I just dropped the `android` off of the front of `<item name="android:colorPrimary">` it worked. Do you know how to change the colors of the titles like `<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/notification_settings">`. Does that generally follow the accent color? Also if you make an answer I'd like to accept it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `AppCompat`, you should use the non-prefixed versions of each attribute - this ensures that they are available on all API levels (unlike the `android:` ones, which only work on API21+ for example):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```