# How to change icon of SwitchPreference when it changes state from off to on?

Tags: android, android-layout, switchpreference

I would like to change the icon in my SwitchPreference (e.g. for enabling notification sound) once the state is changed from on to off and vice versa.

This is the code of my SwitchPreference:

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_key_sound"
    android:id="@+id/pref_key_sound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="@string/pref_sound"
    android:summaryOff="Off"
    android:summaryOn ="On"
    android:showText="true"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_volume"
/>
```

As you can see here I set just a fixed icon.

Comment: That takes quite a bit of work to accomplish. This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235829/custom-switchpreference-in-android In cases where I have to do this sort of customizations I resort to using custom classes.

Comment: @JanithaR There is a bit easier solutions- Instead of making custom layout and apllying it. You can apply the thumb and track attributes trough styles. Your Theme:
<style name="shinySwitch" parent="AppCOmpat">
<item name="android:switchStyle">switchStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="switchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
        <item name="android:thumb">yourThumb</item>
        <item name="android:track">yourTrack</item>
    </style>

Comment: @X3Btel Hmmm... I guess that's easier but I believe this leads to issues in many cases. I cannot exaclty recall why I stuck with creating custom classes now, sorry about that. Anyways if that's the solution you're suggesting then better educate him how to do the 9 patch drawables correctly as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch

Comment: Creating a custom selector like: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_volume_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_volume" />

</selector>  shouldn't be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In my PreferenceActivity I registered my SharedPreferences to listen for changes like this: `prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

In the `onSharedPreferenceChanged`callback I just checked if the key was corresponding to the one of my `SwitchPreference` and if yes, I checked whether it was selected or not by getting the boolean value stored in the `SharedPreferences`:

`boolean isOn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_key_sound), true);`

Afterwards I obtained a reference to my SwitchPreference:

```
SwitchPreference switchPreference = (SwitchPreference) settingsFragment.findPreference("pref_key_sound");
```

and simply changed the icon based on the boolean `isOn` since the value is updated each time the switch is pressed:

```
if (isOn) {

     switchPreference.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_volume);

   } else {

      switchPreference.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_volume_off);

   }
```

Simple as that! :) Hope it is clear!