# Changing android preference icon with SwitchPreference Setting

Tags: android, xml

I have a `SwitchPreference` in my android app which can be set to "`on`" or "`off`". I have an icon for this `SwitchPreference`. XML code below

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:title="@string/psm_pinterest"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="@string/pref_social_pinterest"
    android:icon="@drawable/pinterest_bw"
    android:summaryOn="@string/psm_pinterest_summary_on"
    android:summaryOff="@string/psm_pinterest_summary_off"/>
```

However, I also want the `icon` to change as and when the `SwitchPreference` is changed. Is there anyway to do it via XML? I tried to create a "`drawable`" xml using the "state" settings but none of the "states" are getting called when I change the `SwitchPreference` setting.

I am now handling this programatically but I am looking at a more efficient way to do it via XML itself. Appreciate the help

Comment: Afaik, that's not possible to do solely with xml.

Comment: @azizbekian - As always, appreciate your expert views....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research and consultation, it seems that there is really no way to do it in only XML without writing any associated code for now. I will keep a lookout and if this becomes possible, I will update the anser.

Answer (score 1):

By following of what you want, to get icon changed by just create xml without handled programmatically is need much to do to accomplish, and still need some code in your java/kotlin.

### Here what was i tried:

I've been try this way and it's worked, the icon changed, but once i said, this way is not recommended **in my opinion**. Handling icon change programmatically is better and more effective.

#### Adjust your SwitchPreference

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:title="@string/psm_pinterest"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="@string/pref_social_pinterest"/>
```

#### First, in your Setting fragment/activity

Set layout to replace view of the SwitchPreference and create the switch listener too.
For example, like this:

```
SwitchPreference prefSocPin = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_social_pinterest));
prefSocPin.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.pinterest_switch); // THIS IS THE KEY OF ALL THIS. HERE YOU SET A CUSTOM LAYOUT FOR PreferenceSwitch

prefSocPin.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // Here you can enable/disable whatever you need to
        return true;
    }
});
```

#### Second, create layout pinterest_switch.xml

For example, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pinterest_switch_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:track="@drawable/pinterest_track" 
    android:thumb="@drawable/pinterest_thumb"/>
```

#### Third, in the drawable

Same with your first try, create xml in drawable for state listener, but this time you will create 2 items. Once for track, once for thumb.

**pinterest_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg"/>

</selector>
```

**pinterest_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated" android:state_checked="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb"/>

</selector>
```

I'm following [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235829/custom-switchpreference-in-android) with some adjustment to your need.

> In summary, change icon by just creating xml is a harder work and
>   uneffective way, in my opinion.
>   Well, still I'm trying to answer of what you want. Enjoy.

Comment: Sorry I am looking at a more efficient way. Your answer is obviously less efficient. Appreciate your effort though...

Comment: the effective way is only set the icon programmatically, far i know.